# jQuery switching lists with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a bit complex list and I wish after clicking on element with class ".recipes",  display it inside paragraph but after clicking on button prev or next, I wish to switch to previous or next element with same class name. I know already how to switch the list if they are next to each other but after putting them inside different parents it seems more complicated:

```
<div>
    <button class="prev">prev</button>
    <button class="next">next</button>
    <p class="showRecipies"></p>
    <ul class="listOfRecipies">
        <li>
            <ul class="particularRecipie">
                <li class="timeOfPreparation">3:20</li>
                <li class="recipies">Drinks</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul class="particularRecipie">
                <li class="timeOfPreparation">3:20</li>
                <li class="recipies">Vegetables</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul class="particularRecipie">
                <li class="timeOfPreparation">3:20</li>
                <li class="recipies">Meat</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul class="particularRecipie">
                <li class="timeOfPreparation">3:20</li>
                <li class="recipies">Fruits</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul class="particularRecipie">
                <li class="timeOfPreparation">3:20</li>
                <li class="recipies">Others</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

To show clicked element:

```
 $(".recipies").on("click", function() {
        $(".recipies.active").add($(this)).toggleClass("active");
        var recipieValue = $(this).text();
        var showRecipies = document.querySelector(".showRecipies");

        showRecipies.innerHTML = recipieValue;
    });
```

and to show previous element with class "recipes" I got from another person on this forum is here however because classes have different parents now, it doesn't work, I thought that i can add more parents() and because of that find previous or next ".recipes" but it didn't work out:

```
$(".prev").click(function() {
    var isFirst = $(".recipies.active").is(":first-child");
    if(isFirst){
        $(this).parent().find(".recipies:last").trigger("click");
    } else {
        $(".recipies.active").prev().trigger("click");
    }
});
```

Comment: `$(".recipies.active").prev()` will find the previous li in the same ul which is the timeOfPreparation. Try `$(".recipies.active").parent().parent().prev().find(".recipies")`

Comment: Dude you are best:) Thanks you so much it works!

Comment: @MajidAkbari, post that as an answer so it can be accepted and upvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out:

```js
$(".recipies").on("click", function() {
  $(".recipies.active").add($(this)).toggleClass("active");
  var recipieValue = $(this).text();
  var showRecipies = document.querySelector(".showRecipies");

  showRecipies.innerHTML = recipieValue;
});

$(".prev").click(function() {
  var isFirst = $(".recipies.active").text() == $($(".recipies").get(0)).text();
  if (isFirst) {
    $(this).parent().find(".recipies:last").trigger("click");
  } else {
    $(".recipies.active").parent().parent().prev().find(".recipies").trigger("click");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button class="prev">prev</button>
  <button class="next">next</button>
  <p class="showRecipies"></p>
  <ul class="listOfRecipies">
    <li>
      <ul class="particularRecipie">
        <li class="timeOfPreparation">3:20</li>
        <li class="recipies">Drinks</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ul class="particularRecipie">
        <li class="timeOfPreparation">3:20</li>
        <li class="recipies">Vegetables</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ul class="particularRecipie">
        <li class="timeOfPreparation">3:20</li>
        <li class="recipies">Meat</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ul class="particularRecipie">
        <li class="timeOfPreparation">3:20</li>
        <li class="recipies">Fruits</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ul class="particularRecipie">
        <li class="timeOfPreparation">3:20</li>
        <li class="recipies">Others</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```